# when exactly does a non static public ip adress change?

Tags: router, dhcp, ip

i've heard somewhere that my public ip adress is changed every 24h (on midnight) by my router. At least when I make a hard reset of that router.

=> But how does that relate to e.g. the long-term banning system on IRC chats which is maintained even months, i think? They rely on user indentification by IP adresses, because the username can be changed easily.

Comment: Questions from ISP end-users are off-topic. You will need to ask your ISP.

Comment: ...or maybe [I'm not sure if this is on-topic there] ask on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jozef Woods pointed out, it is up to your ISP when your dynamic IP adress might change. With all the ISPs that I've encountered, the IP adress has remained the same until i've chosen to change it either by turning of my modem/router and keep it of for a while or changed the mac adress/interface identifier facing the ISP(making the ISP believe it is a different device).

As to your question regarding ip bans. They are a bit useless when it comes to clients with dynamic IPs. As you pointed out, a nickname can easily be changed if it would be banned and the same goes for IPs if you're on a dynamic range. But in lack of better alternatives IP bans are pretty easy to implement and somewhat effective because some users are on static IPs and others don't know how to change IP and hence keep the same banned IP unless the ISP has an automatic forced renewal of the IP adresses.

Answer (score 0):

Depends largely on who's handing it out and what settings they've got. I'll use my home address as an example. For my previous ISP, my devices were left on 24/7, and I had the same address for around 2 years (even followed me across a house move, which I wasn't expecting).

My current one, on the other hand, seems to reset it around every month (makes all my services stutter until they find themselves again).